# Cannot get response.get() to load full webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

When I go to scrape https://www.onthesnow.com/epic-pass/skireport for the names of all the ski resorts listed, I'm running into an issue where some of the ski resorts don't show up in my output. Here's my current code:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.onthesnow.com/epic-pass/skireport"
response = requests.get(url)
response.text
```

The current output gives all resorts up to Mont Sainte Anne, but then it skips to the resorts at the bottom of the webpage under "closed resorts". I notice that when you scroll down the webpage in a browser that the missing resort names need to be scrolled down to before they will load. How do I make my response.get() obtain all of the HTML, even the HTML that still needs to load?

Comment: It's likely that JS is populating the HTML dynamically.

Comment: If you inspect the page and look at the network tab you can see how the JS is making requests to load particular data. In this case as you scroll you will see lines like: https://www.onthesnow.com/_next/data/0.6.33_en-US/ski-resort.json and https://www.onthesnow.com/_next/data/0.6.33_en-US/mountain-collective/skireport.json being made.  You could probably attempt to reverse engineer how these calls are put together to dynamically find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The data you see is loaded from external URL in Json form. To load it, you can use this example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://api.onthesnow.com/api/v2/region/1291/resorts/1/page/1?limit=999"

data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i, d in enumerate(data["data"], 1):
    print(i, d["title"])
```

Prints:

```
1 Beaver Creek
2 Breckenridge
3 Brides les Bains
4 Courchevel
5 Crested Butte Mountain Resort
6 Fernie Alpine
7 Folgàrida - Marilléva
8 Heavenly
9 Keystone
10 Kicking Horse
11 Kimberley
12 Kirkwood
13 La Tania
14 Les Menuires
15 Madonna di Campiglio
16 Meribel
17 Mont Sainte Anne
18 Nakiska Ski Area
19 Nendaz
20 Northstar California
21 Okemo Mountain Resort
22 Orelle
23 Park City
24 Pontedilegno - Tonale
25 Saint Martin de Belleville
26 Snowbasin
27 Stevens Pass Resort
28 Stoneham
29 Stowe Mountain
30 Sun Valley
31 Thyon 2000
32 Vail
33 Val Thorens
34 Verbier
35 Veysonnaz
36 Whistler Blackcomb
```

Comment: Infact, it looks like they have a publicly documented API! http://docs.clientservice.onthesnow.com/docs/index.html